# How to retrieve element from ArrayList containing long array

Tags: java, arraylist

How to retrieve element from `ArrayList<long[]>`?

I wrote like this:

```
ArrayList<long []>  dp=new ArrayList<>();

//m is no of rows in Arraylist
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    dp.add(new long[n]);   //n is length of each long array
    //so I created array of m row n column
}
```

Now how to get each element?

Comment: `dp.get(someIndex)[some_other_index]` ?

Comment: Please add an appropiate language tag. An array list is part in multiple programming languages.

Comment: No language no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every element in that list is an array... so you need to carefully add those by:
using anonymous arrays  `new long[] { 1L, 2L, 3L }`
or especifying the size using the new keyword `new long[5]`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<long[]> dp = new ArrayList<>();
    // add 3 arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        dp.add(new long[] { 1L, 2L, 3L });
    }
    // add a new array of size 5
    dp.add(new long[5]); //all are by defaul 0
    // get the info from array
    for (long[] ls : dp) {
        for (long l : ls) {
            System.out.println("long:" + l);
        }
        System.out.println("next element in the list");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to add the appropiate language tag to the question? It seems you know the language (looks like Java). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You get the arrays the same way you get anything from an `ArrayList`. For example, to get the tenth `long[]` stored in the `ArrayList`, you'd use the `get` method:

```java
long[] tenthArray = dp.get(9);
```

Comment: to get 8th element in 10 row wrote like                                                             
     long l=dp.get(9)[7];   an dit works. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You could also have an ArrayList of objetcs that contain an array of longs inside. But the problem so far with your code is that you are not putting any values in each long array.

```
public class NewClass {

    private static class MyObject {
        private long []v;

        public MyObject(int n) {
            v = new long[n];
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String x = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                x += v[i] + " ";
            }
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MyObject> dp = new ArrayList();
        int m = 3;
        int n = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            dp.add(new MyObject(n));
        }

        for (MyObject ls : dp) {
            System.out.println(ls);
        }
    }
}
```